# Can I add my own feeds in the news app in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10

In Windows 8.1 I used to be able to add my own news feeds, rss, etc. The version in W10 doesn't seem to have that option (to me, that would make it useless). Does anybody know if it can be made?